# shows an error when i run a javafx video player

Tags: java, javafx

I tried to build a video play in java using javafx in which you add the file path to where the video is stored on your computer,

but got an error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class javafxapplication1.MoviePlayer
```

when I tried to run class

```
package javafxapplication1;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaView;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 * @author goldAnthony
 */
public class MoviePlayer extends Application {

    public static void main (String [] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Group root = new Group();

        Media media = new Media("C:\\Users\\goldAnthony\\Videos\\Whistle.mp4");
        MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(media);
        MediaView view = new MediaView(player);

        root.getChildren().add(view);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400, Color.BLACK);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        player.play();
    }
}
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're running it from Netbeans and running the individual file - do a clean and build on the project then run the actual project (using F6 rather than Shift+F6) and it should run ok.

Failing that, try just copying the code into a new project. Either way, this remains a build / run issue rather than an issue with your code.

Comment: hello, i did exactly as you said, but when i press f6, it says shows an error unable to find class javaApplication1.JavaApplication1

Comment: @MastaOpec That means you haven't set the main class properly. Right click on the project, go to properties, click on the "Run" category (left hand panel), and under "Application class" change it to `javafxapplication1.MoviePlayer`.

Comment: @beny120 sorry i was away, i tried what you just told me, but now it brings the following error "Unable to find application class name"

Comment: @MastaOpec To be honest at this point it may just be quicker to create a new project, call it `MoviePlayer` and copy that code above into it!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of accessing the media file like:

```
Media media = new Media("C:\\Users\\goldAnthony\\Videos\\Whistle.mp4");
```

try to access the media file like:

```
Media media = new Media("file://C:/Users/goldAnthony/Videos/Whistle.mp4");
```

I think your problem will be disolve.